# disable [DEPRECATION WARNING] on python-version while Ansible execution

Tags: ansible

I am getting a `DEPRECATION WARNING` when running ansible ad-hoc command or executing a playbook like this:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.6.8 (default, Aug 18
 2020, 08:33:21) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)].
```

how can I disable/surpress that?

Answer (score 3):

set `deprecation_warnings=False` in the `[defaults]` section of your effective configuration file (i.e. `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`, `~/.ansible.cfg`)

Comment: And someday you will be surprised that your playbooks don't work anymore because Ansible was updated. Depreciation notices are there for a reason.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I wouldn't be surprised. There are so many breaking changes post-2.9 -- which have no warnings at all -- that Red Hat deliberately held back to 2.9 for RHEL 8 and Ansible Tower. Going past 2.9 almost everyone is going to have to make changes to all but the most trivial playbooks and roles.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your hosts to use a supported version of python.

Comment: thx for making that point. However, that was not exactly the issue in question. Still it is probably a good idea to keep python fresh, but there may be situations (and that is more or less a scenario I was referring to here) where you have reasons to stay on a python version for a little longer and just do not want to see the WARNING each and every time. Sorry, if I did not make that clear enough.